# Does Airflow with multiple Schedulers and LocalExecutor provide a complete solution for horizontal scale up?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x

Are airflow tasks processed by local workers that reside in the Scheduler component when using LocalExecutor?
So if in practice, it's possible to set Schedulers to perform tasks by their own local workers,
does this mean, that setting up Airflow with multiple Schedulers provides a solution for horizontal scale up even with LocalExecutor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Airflow's LocalExecutor, the scheduler process spawns (or forks) subprocesses that perform tasks, by default at most 32, configured by `AIRFLOW__CORE__PARALLELISM`.

Before it was possible to have multiple schedulers, the LocalExecutor was really meant for running on a single machine. With multiple schedulers, it is indeed possible to scale horizontally. However, scaling out the "brains" rather than (or more precisely -- together with) the "workers" is something you don't see much, in any distributed system.

I don't have concrete numbers to back up how this performs for Airflow, but for example Astronomer limits the number of schedulers to 4, GCP Composer to 10, and AWS MWAA to 5. You can scale the number of workers on all those services to more than that. When you need horizontal scalability, I'd choose the CeleryExecutor or KubernetesExecutor instead, which were developed with horizontal scalability in mind from the start and can run and scale out tasks on a machine separate from the scheduler process.

*Note: The term "workers" only applies to the CeleryExecutor, where you start separate "worker" processes that perform tasks.*

Comment: Yes it's clear that such setup isn't ideal because it doesn't allow scaling out Schedulers and Workers separately. Also, since the number of schedulers is limited it makes the number of subprocesses that perform tasks (what I called local workers) limited as well. But still it seems that multiple Schedulers with LocalExecutor may be sufficient for production environment with mild load as a simple and cheap solution.

Comment: A single scheduler with LocalExecutor is a simple and cheap solution. If you've gotten to the stage where you need multiple schedulers, why not just use the CeleryExecutor + workers? It isn't that much more complicated and you'll need them eventually if you've gotten to the stage where you have more than one scheduler.

Comment: Setup Airflow with CeleryExecutor requires setup a Celery backend (RabbitMQ, Redis). So, it seems not so simple. I thought to go on Kubernetes Executor when it will be required, the only con I see that it invokes K8S pod for every task what can make things work slowly.